# ¿Cómo hacer un filtro con lista de parámetros en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, array, filtro

Tengo una lista de objetos de la forma:

```
{ ... categories: ['categoria1', 'categoria2', ..., 'categoriaN'], ... }
```

Quiero, dado un array con ciertos nombres de categorías, por ejemplo:

```
filtro = ['categoria3', 'categoria5', 'categoria7']
```

Obtener todos los elementos de mi lista de objetos que tengan exactamente las mismas categorías que mi array `filtro`.

Estuve probando algunas cosas que no funcionan bien (devuelve una lista de objetos que tienen alguna de las categorías del array `filtro`).

Lo que estoy buscando son sugerencias de cómo encarar el problema o recomendaciones de herramientas predeterminadas (métodos) de JavaScript que puedan ser útiles. Lo que estoy intentando hacer es un filtro para un carrito de compras.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow revisa [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y date un [Tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) por la plataforma y gana tu primer medalla. 
Muestra lo que haz intentado para resolver tu problema y los errores que tuviste durante el proceso.

Comment: Esto te puede servir https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/448377/55132