# ¿Cómo puedo lograr este tipo de búsqueda?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

En esta pequeña aplicación intento filtrar algunos datos, he estado probando pero he fallado.

A continuación le mostraré la estructura de la aplicación:

Este es el **JSON**:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "nombre": "Pedro",
        "apellido": "Gutierez",
        "edad": 35
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "nombre": "Susana",
        "apellido": "Martinez",
        "edad": 45
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "nombre": "Sebastian",
        "apellido": "Gómez",
        "edad": 50
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "nombre": "Analía",
        "apellido": "Torres",
        "edad": 35
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "nombre": "Germán",
        "apellido": "Sandez",
        "edad": 35
    }
]
```

Cuando ingrese algún dato, me gustaría que se traigan los datos coincidentes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu escenario tienes que cuando se pulsa el botón, se ejecuta el método `filtrandoPersonas`, pero ese método **devuelve** el resultado, que no lo estás guardando en ningún sitio. Recuerda que filter te devuelve un nuevo array, no modifica el existente.

Podrías hacer algo como:

```js
  personas: Persona[];
  filtrado: Persona[] = [];
  palabrasClave: any = '';

  constructor(private service: PersonasService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.traerLasPersonas(); // te traes todas las personas
    this.filtrado = this.personas; //en un primer momento, se muestran todas
  }

  traerLasPersonas() {
    this.personas = this.service.getPersonas();
    console.log(this.personas);
  }

  filtrandoPersonas() {
    console.log(this.palabrasClave);
    const filtro = this.palabrasClave.toLocaleLowerCase()
    //actualizamos el filtro
    this.filtrado = this.personas.filter(persona=> {
      const nombreCompleto = persona.nombre + " " + persona.apellido;
      return nombreCompleto.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filtro) !== -1;
    });
  }
```

Y entonces en tu plantilla tendrías que cambiar el bucle a

```
<tr *ngFor="let persona of filtrado">
```

Answer (score 0):

Agrego un ejemplo que filtra todas las coincidencias de las palabras de la búsqueda.

```js
let nombres=[{id:1,nombre:"Pedro",apellido:"Gutierez",edad:35},{id:2,nombre:"Susana",apellido:"Martinez",edad:45},{id:3,nombre:"Sebastian",apellido:"Gómez",edad:50},{id:4,nombre:"Analía",apellido:"Torres",edad:35},{id:5,nombre:"Germán",apellido:"Sandez",edad:35}];


// palalabras de la búsqueda
let busqueda = "Pedro Sebastian"
// separar cada palabra
let tokens = busqueda.toLowerCase().split(' ')
// filtrar el arreglo nombres donde el nombre esté incluido
// dentro del arreglo de palabras de búsqueda
let nombresFiltrados = nombres.filter(n => tokens.some(t => t == n.nombre.toLowerCase()))

console.log(nombresFiltrados)
```